# How is concurrency managed by Firestore using Cloud Functions v2?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, concurrency, google-cloud-functions

Context: A Cloud Function v2 that updates a Firestore document. 100 users used the web application at the same time and the Cloud Function v2 is running 100 times at the same time.

How does Firestore react? How will the document be updated?

Comment: It sounds like the Cloud Functions aspect here is somewhat irrelevant - concurrency can come from anywhere. Perhaps https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/transaction-data-contention answers the Firestore aspect?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for answer and the doc link. I have edited the message and questions.

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd clarify what aspect of the question *isn't* answered by the link, or which aspect of that documentation you don't understand.